# Problem Uploading Files Using Chilkat sFTP

Tags: chilkat

File upload returns "Status Code 8 - Invalid Parameter" response. Looking for some advice on what might be causing this.

I'm using Chilkat sFTP to transfer and receive files to and from multiple partners without issue but for a new partner I'm seeing the following error. The partner's tech team are asking if a passive connection is being invoked but I can't see any properties within Chilkat which would enable me to change this.

Log message:

> ```
> ChilkatLog:
>   OpenFile:
>     DllDate: Jul 31 2014
>     ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.43
>     UnlockPrefix: NORVICSSH
>     Username: LVPAPP005:scheduleradminprod
>     Architecture: Little Endian; 64-bit
>     Language: .NET 2.0 / x64
>     VerboseLogging: 0
>     SshVersion: SSH-2.0-FTP Server ready
>     SftpVersion: 3
>     sftpOpenFile:
>       remotePath: \GIB_DAILY_CENTAUR_POSITIONS_20190403.CSV
>       access: writeOnly
>       createDisposition: createTruncate
>       v3Flags: 0x1a
>       Sent FXP_OPEN
>       StatusResponseFromServer:
>         Request: FXP_OPEN
>         InformationReceivedFromServer:
>           StatusCode: 8
>           StatusMessage: Invalid parameter
>         --InformationReceivedFromServer
>       --StatusResponseFromServer
>     --sftpOpenFile
>     Failed.
>   --OpenFile
> --ChilkatLog
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing the SSH/SFTP protocol with the FTP protocol.  The two are entirely different protocols.   The concept of "passive" data transfers does not exist in SSH/SFTP as it does in the FTP protocol.